# how to log in to specific postgresql version

Tags: server, postgresql

I have multiple versions of postgresql installed on my ubuntu box. 
9.3 is for real stuff.  I just installed 9.4 to do some tests with replication.

Here's why I think I have two versions running:

```
test@testdev:/usr/lib/postgresql$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.3 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
9.4 main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log
test@testdev:/usr/lib/postgresql$
```

Also:

```
test@testdev:/usr/lib/postgresql$ ls
9.3  9.4
```

And finally:

```
test@testdev:~$ /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
     * Error: You must run this program as the cluster owner (postgres) or root [fail]
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.4 database server
     * Error: You must run this program as the cluster owner (postgres) or root [fail]
```

**Questions:**

I have two questions.

1. Assuming  I have correctly installed two different servers, how do I launch command lines for each version of the servers i have?

   I normally log into the 9.3 databases by doing something like this:

> ```
> test@testdev:/usr/lib/postgresql$ sudo -i -u postgres
> postgres@testdev:~$ psql
> psql (9.4.1, server 9.3.5)
> Type "help" for help.
> postgres=# select version();
>
>                                              version                                                
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 4.9.1, 64-bit
> (1 row)
> ```

2. what's the **"psql (9.4.1, server 9.3.5)"** reference above ?
   Does it mean I have a 9.4.1 client running on a 9.3 server?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

i just tried:

```
test@testdev:/usr/lib/postgresql$ sudo -i -u postgres:5433
sudo: unknown user: postgres:5433
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

and also:

```
test@testdev:/usr/lib/postgresql$ sudo -i -u postgres --port 5433
sudo: unrecognized option '--port'
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] file ...
```

Comment: @Rinzwind neither one of those options worked.Please refer to my "EDIT 1" for results:

Comment: "sudo -i -u postgres:5433" or "sudo -i -u postgres --port 5433" when did I claim that? lol. Sorry I missed you used 2 commands; all the postgress things need to go with the "psql" command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Assuming I have correctly installed two different servers, how do I launch command lines for each version of the servers i have?

The command to connect to a specific port for postgres is:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5433
```

I would assume you need to use ...

```
sudo -i -u postgres
psql -p 5433
```

as a bare minimum (5432 is the default). From the [psql man](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html):

```
-p port
--port=port

Specifies the TCP port or the local Unix-domain socket file extension 
on which the server is listening for connections. 
Defaults to the value of the PGPORT environment variable or, 
if not set, to the port specified at compile time, usually 5432
```

> What's the "psql (9.4.1, server 9.3.5)" reference above ?

- "psql 9.4.1" is the psql version. That script probably got updated when you installed the 9.4 server. `psql --version` shows the version of a command. You will need the 9.4.1 version of psql to support 9.4 server and it probably is backwards compatible with 9.3 but the 9.3 version of psql will not support the 9.4 server. So seems correct to me.
- "server 9.3.5" is the server.